# Impedance matching transformer simulation

Tags: transformer, inductor, impedance, impedance-matching

Here is an example of a transformer that converts 10Ohm load into 1kOhm
[image: circuit]

And the AC simulation result
[image: simulation]

From my understanding the source sees the transformer as an inductor in parallel with a converted impedance:
$$
Z_{p} = j\omega L_{p} || NZ_{load}
$$

So why the graph continues to rise instead of approaching 1k asymptotically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why the graph continues to rise instead of approaching 1k asymptotically?

Because K1 is not equal to 1, which means that the "transformer" is perfect.

If a transformer is not perfect, then there is the "coupling" inductance which is always present.

Here are the input impedances z1 seen (when k=? and when k=1).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should consider this omission: -

[image]

Leakage inductance equals: -

$$(1 - 0.99) \times 100 \text{ henry} = 1 \text{ henry}$$.

K = 0.99 (in your question). If you set it to unity there would be no leakage inductance. Maybe try this out to convince yourself.

At 1 kHz, the leakage is 6,283 Ω in series with 1,000 Ω produced by the 10 Ω being reflected to the primary. That's a total of 6,362 Ω and that looks about right on your graph.